# Blowfish decrypting hex encoded string

Tags: java, decode, blowfish

I'm trying to decrypt **Hex** encoded string via **Blowfish**. But the result is different from the correct one.

```
String s="a1d0534e4baf9e670bde8670caee8b87"
String decKey = "R=U!LH$O2B#";
Cipher m_decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
m_decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(decKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish"));
byte[] decrypted = m_decrypt.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(s.toCharArray()));
```

Correct result from site: c6    b7  8d  52  31  35  30  34  31  38  38  36  39  37  02  02

My result: -58 -73 -115 82 49 53 48 52 49 56 56 54 57 55

I check the correct byte array with mine on this site http://blowfish.online-domain-tools.com/

Comment: Thanks, i will fix post name.

Comment: Blowfish is past its "best used by" date, even its author no longer uses it.

Comment: Is "My result" decimal and "Correct result from site" hexadecimal? Those are different encodings, different encodings of the same data will be different. The final `02 02` from the correct result is two bytes of padding which is usually transparently removed.

Comment: Thank you, i found my mistake, it was different encodings really. My inattention...

Comment: @zaph indeed, usually padding is transparently removed, but I assume the web page simply added the padding not telling anybody about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correect result: `c6 b7 8d 52 31 35 30 34 31 38 38 36 39 37 02 02`
is in hex encoding and contains two bytes of padding.

My result: `-58 -73 -115 82 49 53 48 52 49 56 56 54 57 55`
in in signed decimal encoding without the padding bytes.

They are the same value just in different encodings where "My result" has had the padding removed as is usual.